# Counting of votes

Tags: support, voting, account-suspension

I have an account on Stack Overflow. The account is currently banned for a few days. I got a few upvotes to some of my previous answers. Will these upvotes get added to my reputation or will it just be ignored?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I cant find my answer in the question u have suggested . can u pls help?

Comment: "After the suspension period ... your rep will be recalculated" - this is the answer to your question.

Comment: And just  a friendly advice: we are not on chat here. You are expected to write in full and formal English, otherwise people will have hard time understanding what you write. (with all of your accounts)

Answer (score -1):

They will be added to your account because the account still exists in the database.

Comment: are you sure abt it?

Comment: @Mohit He is right. But strange explanation...

Comment: Yes, regardless of suspension the account still exists in the stack overflow database and can collect reputation

Comment: The account is not gaining reputation *now* however. When suspension is lifted the reputation is *recalculated* instead. It doesn't matter that the account exists in the database, what matters is that the *votes* exist in the database and are associated with the posts of the OP.